# Apache Virtual Proxypass nodejs application - Empty page

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

I'm running an apache server with a proxypass for my node js application.

Here's what I got in my virtualhost :

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3333/
ProxyPassReverse / htttp://127.0.0.1:3333/
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Basically I want to redirect every request to my nodejs application and it works when I use the direct link.

My issue is when I try to reach it using tier app ( e.g Postman ) it doesn't return my html page. I need tier apps & site to get the meta tags  to share on social networks (FB, TW, ...).

My vhost knowledge is really weak, I'd be really grateful if someone could help me on this case.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3333/
   ProxyPassReverse / htttp://127.0.0.1:3333/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it isn't working. I got a 401 unauthorized on postman. Any clue ?